# Build an HTML select option list in Play

Tags: playframework

I want to do something similar in Play and Java:

```html
<select id="birthyear" name="birthyear">
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2001">2001</option>
<option value="2000">2000</option>
<option value="1999">1999</option>
<option value="1998">1998</option>
<option value="1997">1997</option>
<option value="1996">1996</option>
</select>
```

However I want to be able to give it a start year and an end year and build the select list dynamically.

I ame across [this](http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/9dc0e5be7d9fecf/e7184ab456f50fe4?lnk=gst&q=select&pli=1) but in Scala and Play, but I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Java/Play?

UPDATE:
Read the documentation as provided in the answer and also checked the sample projects that came installed with Play and used the following

```
<div>
     Select birth year of  
     #{select 'yob', items:2012..1900, value:5, id:'select3' /}
   </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Playframework has built in tag #{select} to achive this.

Please go thru the below link, It will help you,

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/tags#select

Answer (score 3):

Did you try this ?

```
<select id="birthyear" name="birthyear">
#{list 2007..1996}
<option value="${_}>${_}</option>
#{/list}
</select>
```